# Excel - Convert dates and currency as text to Excel dates and numbers respectively

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time, text-formatting, cell-format

I frequently copy and paste HTML tables into Excel to do quick aggregate operations (e.g. sums, averages, etc).

In this example, PayPal, their HTML table contains **text** values like

```
    A          | B       | C
1 | Date       | Type    | Net
2 | 5/14/2013  | Payment | $4.70 USD
```

I want to get the actual Date and Currency values from this table into a format that Excel understands (note that my computer is set to "English (United Kingdom)" and I custom-set my Windows Short Date format to `yyyy-MM-dd`) and my default Excel currency is £ GBP.

I create a new column in Excel, `D`, and set the cells to `=VALUE( A2 )` and a Currency column `E` set to `=VALUE( C2 )`.

However for both columns, D and E, Excel gives me the `#VALUE!` error (because it won't parse `MM/dd/yyyy` as a date as it expects `yyyy-MM-dd`, nor `$x.xx USD` as it expects `£x.xx` - so I need to get it to ignore both the initial currency symbol and the trailing 3-character name `USD`)

I don't want to have to write an ugly string-parsing function in VBA (or worse, Excel formula syntax) to convert `"$4.70 USD"` into `4.7` or `"5/14/2013"` into `2013-05-14`, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

Use the Text Import Wizard. You might have this option in the paste button that appears when you paste in your text. If not, it's in the **Data** tab of the ribbon. Click **Text to Columns**. When you get to step 3, import column A as **Date: MDY**. Then you shouldn't have to use the `VALUE` function for your dates.

Comment: That works for dates, but what about the currency values?

Comment: In that case, the formula `=VALUE(LEFT(C2,FIND(" ",C2)))` should chop the trailing "USD" off and convert the text to a number.